# How do I get back in the College of Winterhold?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I completed all of the main quests for the College of Winterhold and didn't go back to the college for a while. When I go back to complete a side quest the gate is closed and it says I need a key to get in. I see people standing on the inside with the orb but too far away to talk to. I have an arch mage key but that won't let me in. Anyone know how I can get back in?

Comment: Do you have any mods installed?

Comment: If you have completed all main story quests (in particular "First Lessons") then this is likely a glitch. If you are on PC you could use commands to fly in or something, but if this on a console, then try waiting or restarting the game (beyond that you may be out of luck unless you have a really old save you want to resort back to). Also, when you say people are standing inside with the orb, do you mean the Eye of Magnus?

Comment: Let me get this straight.  You've got the Arch Mage Key and see people inside with the orb.  Did you pickpocket that key?  Because normally you'd get that key at the same time as the Psijics repo the orb.

Comment: Well I have quite a few mods installed and yes I'm on PC  and no I didn't pickpocket the key. I could try console commands and hope it works.

Comment: Ok well I got in using the tlc flying command thanks everyone!

Comment: @heckingfast is the arch mage key ***the*** arch mage key that allows you access (and ownership) of the arch mage's office up stairs and not another arch mage key a mod has given you? also a console command that might work (has worked for Morrowind, Oblivion, Fallout 3 and New Vegas) is opening the console, clicking on the gate and then typing `unlock`

Comment: Yes it is the actual arch mage key

Comment: Is the Eye of Magnus still in the college?

Comment: I flew in and it was gone. Now my game keeps crashing

Comment: Oh my mistake it wasn't the eye I was seeing it was just a beam of light and the elf lady was standing beside it in the courtyard. But ya know when you walk up the railing and all the beams come on then the gate opens? Yeah that isn't happening...

Answer (score -1):

Just an idea, you can get into the midden if you do a little bit of platforming and mountain climbing, and from there you can get into the College.

And yes, before anyone asks, the midden is infested with enemies and although it is hard to get in, it is possible to do so.